# executing nested 'while' loops within promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to create some nested `'while'` loops within my promises. I start to run into trouble in my `innerFunc` when I am executing `log.asyncCall().then(...)` my IDE is telling me that right away, the arrow function will jump straight to the `.then()` containing `return innerFunc()` without even going into the `if statement`. I think the race conditions are not executing in the order I want them to.

Summary of what I am trying to achieve:

According to `outerFunc` I want to perform `innerFunc` this 3 times.

What `innerFunc` does call `.asyncCall()` over and over again as long as `log` is NOT `null`. If `innerFunc` cannot produce `log`, exit the `'while'` loop.

I'm also having trouble finding a good way to debug promises. I am currently using the debug feature with `WebStorm`.

```
var i = 0 
const outerFunc = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (i < 3) {
      i++
      const innerFunc = () => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          return log.asyncCall().then(lg => {
            if (lg) {
              // some logic
            } else {
              resolve()
            }
          }).then(() => {
            // continue iterating innerFunc()
            return innerFunc();
          });
        })
      };
      // first iteration innerFunc()
      return innerFunc().then(() => {
        // once innerFunc() is complete, reiterate outerFunc()
        return outerFunc();
      });
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  });  
}
```

Comment: NB: `.then(() => { return innerFunc() })` is better written as `.then(innerFunc)`

Comment: also, are you expecting that the `log` variable used in `log.asyncCall` has the value received from the previous iteration?  ( it doesn't )

Comment: @Alnitak sorry bad choice in variable names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a Promise anti-pattern, since you're wrapping a promise in another promise.

I would strongly advise taking `innerFunc` out of the inner scope, and rewriting it thus:

```
const doLogging = () => {
    return log.asyncCall().then(result => {
        if (result) {
            // do stuff
            ...
            return doLogging();
        }
    });
}
```

There's no need for an `else` branch - the inner arrow function will implicitly return `undefined` which will then be wrapped by `.then` into a Promise.

You then want to run this `count` times:

```
const repeatPromise = (f, count) => {
    if (count > 0) {
        return f().then(() => repeatPromise(f, count - 1));
    } else {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
}

const outerFunc = () => repeatPromise(doLogging, 3);
```

In this function the `else` branch is necessary to ensure that the final result is always a Promise.

(NB: as written the `repeatPromise` function won't work properly if the passed function doesn't return a Promise)

Comment: @Liondancer I don't have enough to go on there.  FWIW, I did write some node.js code to test what I had written above and it all worked.